# Tic Tac Toe Java - Tie Game Programming

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I have made a code that checks for wins but i cannot seem to find a away to  make it check for ties, any help will be useful! I also cannot find a way to make it so X or O's are not placed over in the same spot

I tried to make it so that if all the rows or columns did not equal to 60 or 90 it would determine it was a tie, but i later realized that the program would think its a tie after every turn as the rows or columns do not equal 60 or 90

```
import hsa.Console;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class tictactoe88
{ static Console c;
 public static void main(String[]args)

 { c = new Console();

//Drawing the tic tac toe table
c.setColor(Color.black);
c.drawLine(450,250,450,475);
c.drawLine(550,250,550,475);
c.drawLine(350,325,650,325);
c.drawLine(350,400,650,400);

//Declaring variables
int location;
String name1, name2, endGame;
boolean stillPlaying = true;

String[][] names = new String[3][3];

int[][] chart = 
{
  {1,2,3},
  {4,5,6},
  {7,8,9},
};

//Showing players what number corresponds to tic tac toe board
c.println("1  2  3");
c.println("4  5  6");
c.println("7  8  9");

//Asking players for their names
c.print("Player One : ");
name1 = c.readLine ();
c.print("Player Two : ");
name2 = c.readLine ();  



  //Starting of main loop
   while(stillPlaying)
{
  c.setCursor(6,0);
  c.println("Where would you like to place the 'X' " + name1);

  //Making sure the number entered is valid
  while(true)
  {
    try 
    { String locationStr = c.readLine();
      location = Integer.parseInt(locationStr);
      break;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    { c.println("Bad number, please try again.");
    }
  }
  //Drawing the 'X' and adjusting the 2d array's correspomding to the number entered
  {
    if (location == 1)
    {
      c.drawLine(350,250,450,325);
      c.drawLine(450,250,350,325);  
      chart [0][0] = 20;
    }
    else if (location == 2)
    {
      c.drawLine(450,250,550,325);
      c.drawLine(550,250,450,325);    
      chart [0][1] = 20;
    }
    else if(location == 3)
    { 
      c.drawLine(550,250,650,325);
      c.drawLine(650,250,550,325);  
      chart [0][2] = 20;
    }
    else if (location == 4)
    { 
      c.drawLine(350,325,450,400);
      c.drawLine(350,400,450,325);
      chart [1][0] = 20;
    }
    else if (location == 5)
    { 
      c.drawLine(450,325,550,400);
      c.drawLine(450,400,550,325); 
      chart [1][1] = 20;
    }
    else if (location == 6)
    { 
      c.drawLine(550,325,650,400);
      c.drawLine(550,400,650,325);
      chart [1][2] = 20;
    }
    else if (location == 7)
    {  
      c.drawLine(350,400,450,475);
      c.drawLine(350,475,450,400);   
      chart [2][0] = 20;
    }
    else if (location == 8)
    {  
      c.drawLine(450,400,550,475);
      c.drawLine(450,475,550,400); 
      chart [2][1] = 20;
    }
    else if (location == 9)
    { 
      c.drawLine(550,400,650,475);
      c.drawLine(550,475,650,400); 
      chart [2][2] = 20;
    }  
  }
```

This is currently how it checks for a winner,

```
  //Checks the winner by all 8 possibilities
  if (chart[0][0]+chart[0][1]+chart[0][2] == 60||
      chart[1][0]+chart[1][1]+chart[0][2] == 60||
      chart[2][0]+chart[2][1]+chart[2][2] == 60||
      chart[0][0]+chart[1][1]+chart[2][2] == 60||
      chart[2][0]+chart[1][1]+chart[0][2] == 60||
      chart[0][0]+chart[1][0]+chart[2][0] == 60||
      chart[0][1]+chart[1][1]+chart[2][1] == 60||
      chart[0][2]+chart[1][2]+chart[2][2] == 60)
  {break;}
  c.setCursor(8,0);
  c.println("Where would you like to place 'O' " + name2);
     //Making sure the number entered is valid
    while(true)
    {
    try 
    { String locationStr = c.readLine();
      location = Integer.parseInt(locationStr);
      break;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    { c.println("Bad number, please try again.");
    }
  }
  {
    //Drawing the 'O' and adjusting the 2d array's correspomding to the number entered
    if (location == 1)
    {
      c.drawOval(350,250,100,75); 
      chart [0][0] = 30;
    }
    else if (location == 2)
    {
      c.drawOval(450,250,100,75);  
      chart [0][1] = 30;
    }
    else if(location == 3)
    { 
      c.drawOval(550,250,100,75);  
      chart [0][2] = 30;
    }
    else if (location == 4)
    { 
      c.drawOval(350,325,100,75); 
      chart [1][0] = 30;
    }
    else if (location == 5)
    { 
      c.drawOval(450,325,100,75);  
      chart [1][1] = 30;
    }
    else if (location == 6)
    { 
      c.drawOval(550,325,100,75);
      chart [1][2] = 30;
    }
    else if (location == 7)
    {  
      c.drawOval(350,400,100,75); 
      chart [2][0] = 30;
    }
    else if (location == 8)
    {  
      c.drawOval(450,400,100,75);  
      chart [2][1] = 30;
    }
    else if (location == 9)
    { 
      c.drawOval(550,400,100,75); 
      chart [2][2] = 30;
    }

    This is currently how it checks for a winner,

  //Checks the winner by all 8 possibilities
    if (chart[0][0]+chart[0][1]+chart[0][2] == 90||
        chart[1][0]+chart[1][1]+chart[0][2] == 90||
        chart[2][0]+chart[2][1]+chart[2][2] == 90||
        chart[0][0]+chart[1][1]+chart[2][2] == 90||
        chart[2][0]+chart[1][1]+chart[0][2] == 90||
        chart[0][0]+chart[1][0]+chart[2][0] == 90||
        chart[0][1]+chart[1][1]+chart[2][1] == 90||
        chart[0][2]+chart[1][2]+chart[2][2] == 90)
    {break;}
  }  
}
```

This is how it ends the game,

```
//Ends the game by saying who teh winner is
if (chart[0][0]+chart[0][1]+chart[0][2] == 60||
    chart[1][0]+chart[1][1]+chart[0][2] == 60||
    chart[2][0]+chart[2][1]+chart[2][2] == 60||
    chart[0][0]+chart[1][1]+chart[2][2] == 60||
    chart[2][0]+chart[1][1]+chart[0][2] == 60||
    chart[0][0]+chart[1][0]+chart[2][0] == 60||
    chart[0][1]+chart[1][1]+chart[2][1] == 60||
    chart[0][2]+chart[1][2]+chart[2][2] == 60)
{c.setCursor(10,0);
  c.println("Congratulations "+name1+" you are the winner!");}

else if (chart[0][0]+chart[0][1]+chart[0][2] == 90||
         chart[1][0]+chart[1][1]+chart[0][2] == 90||
         chart[2][0]+chart[2][1]+chart[2][2] == 90||
         chart[0][0]+chart[1][1]+chart[2][2] == 90||
         chart[2][0]+chart[1][1]+chart[0][2] == 90||
         chart[0][0]+chart[1][0]+chart[2][0] == 90||
         chart[0][1]+chart[1][1]+chart[2][1] == 90||
         chart[0][2]+chart[1][2]+chart[2][2] == 90)
{c.setCursor(10,0);
  c.println("Congratulations "+name2+" you are the winner!");}
```

Comment: `if (...) else if (...) else { // draw; }` ?

Comment: You can ask about your homework, but do not paste all the code and paste the exact location of the code.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question